# Separating database, services and IIS to different servers

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, architecture

We're building a web application using Asp.net MVC with Sql Server database. 
This application is supposed to serve hundreds of users or even thousands.
In order for it to be scalable, We want to separate the database to a different server from where the IIS is running.

What's the best way to do this? a reference from the IIS server to the database server using a connection string? won't it slow down performance?

We also want to separate some of the services of this application to a different (third) server.
Does replicating the database to this third services server a good idea? this way we'll reduce the load on the database machine from our first question. How is it done?

Comment: Don't do premature optimalization. You're not Amazon. Start by designing your web site itself in an optimal way: retrieve only data you really need, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's the best way to do this? a reference from the IIS server to the
>   database server using a connection string? won't it slow down
>   performance?

There is no best way because there is only one way to start with. Put the SQL Server on another machine. Finished.

You will have to adjust the connection string. This will introduce latency and the bandwidth is lower than in memory, but practically those things are irrelevant - unless you make a `select * From table` and filter in memory, which hopefully no one does.

Point is - you get more processing power, you get scalability, and the small theoretical impact is neglegible in comparison. If you manage to load up even a 1gigabit network link with data you have either some seriously bad design or some really awkward programming. The higher speed of a non trivial and hopefully build for the purpose database server will far more than outweigh eny small loss of performance.

> Does replicating the database to this third services server a good idea?

How long is a piece of string? It depends - on the services. In general - no. In very few edge cases - yes. How to decide? Experience - and common sense, based on the specific requirements.

Comment: Thanks TomTom. I just didn't get why you refered to memory queries. I meant to the tradeoff between local server queries and remote server queries to the db. But I generally I understand it's a must. Secondly, about the services. One of the services is supposed to an API that (based on an old application we have) would need to handle at the edge cases, up to several hundreds (most times dozens) of requests per minute. Take in account that there are hundreds of users are on the IIS. Would this kind of overload of the API slow doen the IIS? I guess it will... that's my problem.

Comment: Point is that if the server is on the same machine, everything is in the same memory. That is a lot of bandwidth. Every network connection is short circuited (on a modern OS). Lots more bandwidth and lower latency than going over a real network.

Answer (score 0):

It advised to only have SQL Server by it self on a server. and DO NOT run any other applications on the that server/Machine. (even Avoid having Multiple Instances on one machine if possible). As SQL Server by its very nature makes use of all the possible avilable resources to give the best performance and it assumes that it is the only application on that machine.

So hosting Sql Server and IIS on same machine you will start and fight between the two applications for resources.

And obviously if you have sql server on a separate server you will need to tweak your connection string.